# How to make changes/edit on a file present on remote server using python fabric?

Tags: python, automated-tests, fabric

I have a .yml file present in a remote server , I want to make changes on it using python fabric. If it can be done with other python libraries feel free to share.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean appending text to the end of that `.yml` file or just rewriting the whole file?

Comment: rewriting a line in a file

Comment: at the end of the file?

Comment: no at the middle of the file, i just need to change the IP address and port number on that file

Comment: Would you post the file you want to change?

Comment: its a metricbeat.yml file , i just need to change localhost to an IP address and new port
https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to edit a line in the middle of a file which is imo is not possible. 
What you can do, is making a copy of the remote file on your local machine with the desired values you want to change, and then send it back to the remote server.

```
from fabric import Connection as connection, task

@task
def executeTask(ctx):
    with connection(host=dev_server, user=myuser) as c:
         c.put('PATH_TO_YOUR_YML_FILE_LOCALLY', 'PATH_TO_YOUR_REMOTE_YML_FILE')
```

Don't forget to :

1. Replace`dev_server` and `myuser` with the remote server IP and username on it
2. put the code above in a file called `fabfile.py` and you run from your command line `fab executeTask`

The code above is `fabric 2.4` compatible

**EDIT:**
Because of permissions issue you can do the following :

```
@task
def executeTask(ctx):
    with connection(host=dev_server, user=myuser) as c:
         c.put("PATH_TO_YOUR_YML_FILE_LOCALLY") # implicit to remote $HOME
         c.sudo("mv YOUR_FILE_NAME YOUR_DESIRED_LOCATION") # again implicitly with a CWD of $HOME 
         c.sudo("chown root:root YOUR_REMOTE_FILE")
```

Referenc: 
https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1750#issuecomment-406043571

Comment: I'am having problem with file owner , is there any way to change owner as root at one go

Comment: But it doesn't change file owner and group to root

Comment: To be able to change the owner of a file via fabric, you have to connect with a user which has sudo access. Does the user you use to connect has sudo access?

Comment: It worked , thank you so much for your time and effort . But I'am using with sed too , as keeping both as an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to change port number you can use `sed` like this

```
def change_port(filename):
    with cd('/location'):
         run('sed -i "s/old_port_number/new_port_number/g" ' +filename)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort